# php json print array within array

Tags: php, json

I have this json item in my json file

```
{
"results": [
{
    "title": "Brick Mansions",
    "released": "2014",
    "restricted": "12 \u00e1ra",
    "imdb": "6.0\/10  5,532 atkv.",
    "imdbLink": "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt1430612",
    "image": "http:\/\/kvikmyndir.is\/images\/poster\/9260_500.jpg",
    "showtimes": [
        {
            "theater": "Laugar\u00e1sb\u00ed\u00f3",
            "schedule": [
                "20:00",
                "22:00"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to print theater and times under schedule with php.

I have printed everything else. like so... bare in mind that $movys is the object that contains the json content.

```
<?php foreach($movys->results as $movie): ?>
        <h2> <?php echo $movie->title; ?> </h2>
        <div class="posters"><img src="<?php echo $movie->image; ?>" alt="Plakat    fyrir <?php echo $movie->title; ?>"></div>              <ul>
            <li><p> <?php echo $movie->released; ?> </p></li>
            <li><p> <?php echo $movie->restricted; ?> </p></li>
            <li><p> <?php echo $movie->imdb; ?> </p></li>
            <li><p> <?php echo $movie->imdbLink; ?> </p></li>
        </ul>
    ??????  <?php foreach($movys->results{"showtimes"} as $hallo): ?>
??????          <h2><?php echo $hallo->theater; ?></h2>
??????      <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: There are gazillions of solutions around [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+recursive+array)

Comment: Why not `foreach($movie->showtimes as $hallo)`?

Comment: And then `foreach($hallo->schedule as $s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
foreach($movie->showtimes as $showtimes)
{
    echo $showtimes->theater . ":\n";
    foreach ( showtimes->schedule as $schedule )
         echo "> " . $schedule . "\n";
}
```